# What is the correct way to upgrade 7zip on Solaris 10?

Tags: software-installation, solaris, 7z

I currently have an old old version of 7zip installed (`4.55 beta`) on Solaris 10. It is located in `/usr/bin/7z`. Found using `which 7z`

I have downloaded a new version `9.20.1`. The README says to edit the `install.sh` and change `DEST_HOME` to where I want it installed. The default location is `/usr/local` So do I just change this to `/usr/bin/7z`? Will it upgrade/overwrite the old version ok? I want to install this system wide for everyone to use.

Comment: Is there a 7z package available for Solaris 10? Try searching http://unixpackages.com/packages .  It is far preferable to use the package manager (`pkgadd`, `pkgrm`, etc.) than to use some vendor's untrustworthy install script.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, I did find it there - "p7zip – P7zip is a port of 7z and 7za file archiver programs" It doesn't let me have the package for free though. Now I just need to understand this more, how to first find a p7zip package for solaris and then how to use the pkgadd command.

Comment: I am having no luck finding any other p7zip package other than the source package and a linux binary package... (http://www.opencsw.org/package/p7zip/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, don't install locally-built stuff directly under `/usr`, only under `/usr/local`. Normally `/usr/local` comes before `/usr` in the `PATH`, so that the local installation takes precedence over the system default tool. Some system scripts might set `PATH` to exclude `/usr/local` so as to ensure that they're running with the default versions of the system programs.

So follow the `README` and install with `DEST_HOME=/usr/local` (so that the executables will be in `/usr/local/bin`. Make sure that the default `PATH` value for users and in crontabs has `/usr/local/bin` before `/usr/bin` (it should be this way, so that local customizations override system defaults in normal use).

Comment: Can I use gmake to do this? I am trying to follow the README, I did a cp makefile.solaris_x86 makefile.solaris,but when I do "./gmake makefile.solaris it says "gmake: Nothing to be done for makefile.solaris"

Comment: Hm, seems the binary is in this package I have. I ran ./install.sh making sure DEST_HOME was /usr/local which it was already, I see the following (several of the same): -installing /usr/local/bin/7za ./install.sh: strip: not found  -- what does that mean??

Comment: So version 4.55 beta of 7zip already has 7z, 7za and 7zr in /usr/local/bin...that seems to be causing the strip messages....maybe?? When I do "which 7z" it shows /usr/bin/7z

Comment: @DemiSheep It would be `gmake -f makefile.solaris`. The message `strip: not found` indicates that you lack the `strip` program, which removes debugging information from executables. This is not critical (all you save by stripping is a bit of disk space, and maybe a tiny bit of load time (I don't know if that's the case on Solaris)), but it might be a sign that you lack other compilation tools or it might break the makefile. I don't know how to install `strip` on Solaris, it's presumably part of some development package.

Comment: First, thanks for helping such a noob as myself. Second above where I mention a binary it was a linux package so I didn't proceed further with it. Third, when I do "./gmake -f makefile.solaris" I get "gmake: *** No targets. Stop." I'm not quite sure what I need to add to my makefile, so much for thinking it would be mostly setup already. :) I did a "cp makefile.solaris_x86 makefile.solaris and am using this newly created makefile.

Comment: Sorry for all the comments but this could be important: I go to /usr/sfw/bin to use gmake and then I do "./gmake -f /path_to_makefile_/blah2/blah3/blah4/blah5/makefile.solaris"

Comment: So I was able to install a "Patch" we have here in our office to upgrade 7zip. So I leave this problem behind me for now. I believe I needed to modify the makefile.solaris to add missing items needed for gmake to find what it needs to build 7zip. The instructions are not very clear on this probably because they don't put basic compiling instructions into these types of readme files as anyone messing with this should already know those basics. Thanks Gilles!

Answer (score 0):

Another idea you could do is to just copy the makefile.solaris_x86 to Makefile and then run gmake directly. That'll take care of it.

Another suggestion is to check blastwave.org and opencsw.org to see if they might have a newer package available - you might have done this already, I can't tell from what you've said so far.

Hope you can get a good version of 7zip installed to your needs.

EDIT: Sorry, misread your question. I missed that you're running Solaris 10. You may want to search for a package, or see if you've installed the full developer tools onto your system. However, strip is a stage that can be safely skipped.

Answer (score -1):

In Solaris 10 X86 just install OS patch 137322-02 and in SPARC 137321-02 and you are done.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site. We like answers to be more comprehensive here. Please edit your answer and include the commands needed to install the updates you mention and perhaps an explanaton of what they will install.

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful.

Comment: @cuonglm How is this answer a "thank you"?

Comment: @HaukeLaging: my mis-click. It's only a too short answer.